# Toast notification when phone is ringing

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-toast

I am following this example here (http://androidlabs.org/short-experiments/broadcast-receivers/do-something-when-the-phone-rings/):

```
package nl.codestone.cookbook.incomingcallinterceptor;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {  // 1

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {           // 2
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);    // 3
    String msg = "Phone state changed to " + state;

    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {              // 4
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);  // 5
        msg += ". Incoming number is " + incomingNumber;

        // TODO This would be a good place to "Do something when the phone rings" <img src="http://androidlabs.org/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_wink.gif" alt=";-)" class="wp-smiley"> 

    }

    Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

}
```

I have imported the project directly into Eclipse and installed it on my device. Everything compiles and installs correctly with no error messages, but it does not seem to generate a toast message when I receive an incoming call.

I have also tried to manually create the project in case something went astray during the import, but the results are the same. Even though it is installed, it does not seem to do anything when the phone is ringing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) { 
String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
msg += ". Incoming number is " + incomingNumber;
Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Basically, I am trying to make toast inside

```
if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
```

Comment: This does not work. Do you have a test device that you can try my code on?

Comment: You can run it on the emulator itself !